# Making horizontal scroll with images infinite with no break CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a logo portfolio carousel that scrolls horizontally in an infinite way.

I almost have it done, but it will break the animation and not be seamless. I need it to be really an infinite animation with no breaks.

https://jsfiddle.net/nha3grjL/#&togetherjs=sy1LFN4qOJ

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: $boxify-bg-light-dark;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.m-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: scrollText 10s infinite linear;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 250%;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="m-scroll">
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't quite understand the width 250vw setting. Try replacing it with width: fit-content. Then the -50% translate will translate the images to the right plaee.

[I assume that if you are showing different images you know to put a complete copy of them all into the HTML so the -50% works].

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: $boxify-bg-light-dark;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.m-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: scrollText 10s infinite linear;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: fit-content;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="m-scroll">
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" ></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" ></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that replacing your key frame with  this one will work, just write (width * -1) of your image instead of my comment

```
@keyframes scrollText {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(/* Your image width */, 0, 0); 
 }
}
```

sorry for bad formating im new to this

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved with images of different sizes. Just change the ' transform: translateX(x%); ' x% as you want and fine tune margins ans span width:

```css
.scroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.scroll img {
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.m-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: scrollText 20s infinite linear;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 200px;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
      width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
}

span.blank {
    width: 500px !important;
}

span.FARAL {
    width: 800px !important;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(-90%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="m-scroll">
        <span class="blank"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/logo-invd.png" alt="QBX"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/logo-qbx-quadbike.png" alt="QBX"></span>
        <span class="FARAL"><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/FARAL_Automotive_Logotype_RGB.webp" alt="FARAL"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/ADEME.png" alt="ADEME"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/CNRS.png" alt="CNRS"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Logo-INRAE_Quadri-web.jpg" alt="INRAE"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/PolyTech-Clermont.png" alt="INRAE"></span>
        <span><img decoding="async" src="https://neguentropia.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/12/Logo_Universite_Clermont-Auvergne_partenariat_Wikimedia.png" alt="UCA"></span>
        <span class="blank"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My codepen: https://codepen.io/dskillz/pen/KKJrPJR