Horozontal scrolling divs not duplicating the content and only the surrounding div
I have a pen that has a smooth horizontal scrolling of images in a div but it is only cloning the surrounding div and not the IMG or content in the div.
<style>
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.horizontal-scrolling-banner div img {
  max-height:250px;
}
.horizontal-scrolling-banner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.horizontal-scrolling-banner__helper-wrapper {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition-property: left;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}
</style>
<div class="horizontal-scrolling-banner">
  <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/BL_BLCL-lifestyle-phone.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/BL_BLCL_lifestyle-dining.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/LakelandVillageCenter_Coffee.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2024/02/BL_BLCL-Lifestyle-farmersmarket.jpg"></div>
</div>
<script >
(function horizontalScrollingBanner() {
  var banners = document.getElementsByClassName('horizontal-scrolling-banner');
  if (!banners || banners.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  var pxPerSecond = 50;
  setUpElements();
  scrollTheBanners();
  window.addEventListener('resize', setUpElements);

  function setUpElements() {
    for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
      var currentBanner = banners[i];
      var helperWrapperClass = 'horizontal-scrolling-banner__helper-wrapper';
      var currentHelperWrapper = currentBanner.querySelector('.' + helperWrapperClass);
      if (currentHelperWrapper) {
        var clones = currentHelperWrapper.querySelectorAll('[data-clone]');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(clones, function(clone) {
          clone.remove();
        });
        var childrenCount = currentHelperWrapper.children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
          currentBanner.appendChild(currentHelperWrapper.children[0]);
        }
        currentHelperWrapper.remove();
      }

      var children = currentBanner.children;

      var bannerWidth = currentBanner.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      var minWidthToCoverBanner = (bannerWidth * 2) + children[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
      var childrenWidth = Array.prototype.reduce.call(children, function(r, child) {
        return r + child.getBoundingClientRect().width;
      }, 0);
      var currentWidth = childrenWidth;


      do {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(children, function(child) {
          var clone = child.cloneNode();
          clone.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
          clone.dataset.clone = true;
          currentBanner.appendChild(clone);
        });
        currentWidth += childrenWidth;
      } while (currentWidth < minWidthToCoverBanner);

      var transitionHelperWrapper = document.createElement('div');
      transitionHelperWrapper.classList.add('horizontal-scrolling-banner__helper-wrapper');
      var childrenCount = children.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++) {
        transitionHelperWrapper.appendChild(children[0]);
      }
      currentBanner.appendChild(transitionHelperWrapper);
      transitionHelperWrapper.dataset.childrenWidth = childrenWidth;
    }
  }

  function scrollTheBanners() {
    for (var i = 0; i < banners.length; i++) {
      var helperWrapper = banners[i].firstElementChild;
      var childrenWidth = helperWrapper.dataset.childrenWidth;
      var offsetLeft = helperWrapper.offsetLeft;

      if (offsetLeft <= (childrenWidth * -1)) {
        helperWrapper.style.transitionDuration = '0s';
        helperWrapper.style.left = '0px';
        helperWrapper.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
      } else if (helperWrapper.style.left === '' || helperWrapper.style.left === '0px') {
        setTimeout(function() {
          helperWrapper.style.transitionDuration = (childrenWidth / pxPerSecond).toFixed() + 's';
          helperWrapper.style.left = (childrenWidth * -1) + 'px';
        }, 0);
      }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(scrollTheBanners);
  }
})();
    </script>

This is a functioning pen of the issue I am having.
https://codepen.io/abennington/pen/QWPxqyq
Any help is greatly appreciated as to what I have done wrong. :)

Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617963/making-horizontal-scroll-with-images-infinite-with-no-break-css
